# Login ftp with access ssh?

Tags: ssh, ftp, sftp

How to login to an SSH server using an FTP client (such as Filezilla)? I have the server's IP, my .ppk file and its passphrase? Is this possible?

I tried it with `host: XXX.X.XXX.XXX` and the login passphrase but I don't have a password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sftp. Add your key in Filezilla sftp settings like so:
[image: Keyfile adding in filezilla]

and then connect to XXX.X.XXX.XXX and set port to 22, empty password:

[image]

Comment: Yes, its simply and it working! Thanks ;)